# Qml android module QtQuick.* is not installed

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick

Qt 5.12.2
SDK 26.1.1
NDK 21.0.6113669
Сборка под armeabi-v7a
Проект успешно собирается в релизе и устанавливается на телефон, но для для qml сплошные ошибки.
Часть pro файла:

```
QT += core gui
QT += widgets sql multimedia network qml quick quickwidgets

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
QMAKE_LINK += -nostdlib++

TARGET = puzzle
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
DEFINES += "_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"

ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = ../android

DISTFILES += \
    ../android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    ../android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar \
    ../android/gradlew \
    ../android/res/values/libs.xml \
    ../android/build.gradle \
    ../android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties \
    ../android/gradlew.bat \
    ../android/gradle.properties \
    ../android-build/gradle/wrapper/gradle-4.6-bin.zip \

contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH,armeabi-v7a) {
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = ../android
}

RESOURCES += ../resources/resources.qrc
```

Базовый класс для qml окна:

```
#ifndef QMLWIDGET_H
#define QMLWIDGET_H

#include <QQuickWidget>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "qmlbuttonshandler.h"

class QmlWidget: public QQuickWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  QmlWidget(QWidget *parent):QQuickWidget(parent)
  {
    setStyleSheet("background-color: 'gray';");
    this->rootContext()->setContextProperty("buttonsHandler",m_buttonsHandler);
    this->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AlwaysStackOnTop);
    this->setClearColor(Qt::transparent);
  }
protected:
  QmlButtonsHandler *m_buttonsHandler=new QmlButtonsHandler();
  QString m_pathToQmlFile;
};

#endif // QMLWIDGET_H
```

Класс, наследующий базовый класс:

```
#include "updatewidget.h"
#include <QQuickWidget>

UpdateWidget::UpdateWidget(QWidget *parent):
  QmlWidget(parent)
{
  m_pathToQmlFile = "qrc:/qmlWindows/UpdateWindow/UpdateWindow.qml";
  this->setSource(QUrl(m_pathToQmlFile));
  connect(m_buttonsHandler,&QmlButtonsHandler::back,[=] {emit backButtonPressed();});
  connect(m_buttonsHandler,&QmlButtonsHandler::load,[=] {emit loadButtonPressed();});
}
```

Импорт библиотек в UpdateWindow.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
```

[image: Ошибки при использовании приложения]